# C# function to find the delta of two numbers

Tags: c#, math

I just wanted to know if there's anything built into the .net framework where I can easily return the delta between two numbers?  I wrote code that does this but it sounds like something that should be in the framework already.

Comment: Is this question determining whether floats are within a given range ?
(otherwise it's more or less a subtraction problem...

Comment: Subtraction . . . addition's tricky pal.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
delta = Math.Abs(a - b);
```

Comment: Wow...a 24 *character* answer netted 385 rep (and counting).  That's not a bad ratio.

Comment: Also netted him a Reversal badge. Only 207 of these ever handed out! Nice!

Comment: **Word of extreme caution**: *This code will crash* when `a-b` is equal to `Int32.MinValue` because of `System.Overflow` exception. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38702478/465053).

Comment: @RBT: Many functions in the Math class are subject to overflow or underflow.  It's up to the caller of these methods to know what their limitations are.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you are absolutely correct. I investigated bit more on why this happens. The reason turned out to be very trivial as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6265381/465053). The range of number data types is always like `-x` to `(x-1)`. Of course, if I try to accomodate `+x` in the same data type to obtain the absolute value it is bound fail :)

Answer (score 18):

I'm under the impression that "delta" is the difference between two numbers.

Until you tell me differently, I think what you want is:

```
delta = Math.Abs(a - b);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public static int Delta(int a, int b)
{
  int delta = 0;
  if (a == b)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (a < b)
  {
    while (a < b)
    {
      a++;
      delta++;
    }
    return delta;
  }
  else
  {
    while (b < a)
    {
      b++;
      delta++;
    }
    return delta;
  }
}
```

:p

Oh boy, I hope no (future) employer comes across this and stops reading in disgust before he reaches the end of this post..

Answer (score 11):

The Linq version (requires CLR 4.0).

*(cracks fingers, clears throat)*

```
var delta = (from t in Enumerable.Range(a, a).Zip(Enumerable.Range(b, b))
            select Math.Abs(t.Item1 - t.Item2))
            .First();
```

Answer (score 9):

Isn't that what the minus operator does? :p

Comment: Not exactly but nice answer anway ;-)

Answer (score 8):

```
public static int Delta(int a, int b)
{
    return a > 0? Delta(a-1, b-1) : a < 0 ? Delta(a+1, b+1) : b > 0 ? b : -b;
}
```

I think that's even better than @JulianR Delta implementation :-p

Edit: I didn't realize that this was already suggested by @Robert Harvey, credit to him ;-)

Comment: Oh, that's much better. Recursion *and* chained ternary operators!

Comment: Yeah, and it even works! XD I thought that I'd have made some mistake, but surprisingly not ^_^

Answer (score 1):

What is the delta of two numbers?
Delta has a certain meaning in set-theory and infinitesimal calculus, but this doesn't refer to numbers!

If you want to calculate the difference between two numbers a and b, you write `|a - b|` which is `Math.`[`Abs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)`(a - b)` in C#.

Comment: Delta does not have a certain meaning in infinitesimal calculus, it is merely a commonly used symbol.

Comment: Jason, in calculus delta may refer to Diracs delta function and hence has a well defined meaning. A different definition that is widely used is Kroneckers delta. Hence Dario is right, when he asks for a clarification. The OPs question is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to revise JulianR's funny answer above.

The code is shorter, but perhaps more tricky:

```
public static int Delta(int a, int b)
{
  int delta = 0;
  while (a < b)
  {
    ++a;
    ++delta;
  }
  while (b < a)
  {
    ++b;
    ++delta;
  }
  return delta;
}
```

(for the humor-impaired.... this is no more serious than the bizarre question that started the thread)

Answer (score 0):

```
(r1+r2)/2
```

Avarage between two numbers.