# C# Short Error: Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid

Tags: c#, short

I have been encountering this error for my project, which involves working with Digital Audio Signals.

So I have been getting the amplitude values and recently encountered this error. This occurs when the amplitude value encountered is "-32768" upon debugging. I am storing the values in a short[] array.

I have a hunch that it has something to do with max/minimum values (I use Math.Abs) but I am unsure on how to handle it.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Is that value a regular value or a signal of some exceptional situation that you need to handle separately?

Comment: Hi! Its just a regular value. Ive handled it using thresholding function so thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

16 bit signed int (`short`) takes values between -32,768 and 32,767.

Negating -32768, or getting the absolute value, is impossible to do inside a 16 bit signed integer. The value (32,768) is greater than the maximum possible positive value (32,767).

I would not like to advise you how to solve the problem without knowing more details of the algorithms you are using.

Answer (score 10):

The absolute value of -32768 is +32768... but that's outside the range of `short`... hence the error. (You're lucky you're seeing this as an exception... other ways of encountering this oddity can give silent overflow, leading to some very odd results)

Options:

- Special-case this value, e.g. convert to -32767 first, if the exact value doesn't matter too much
- Convert it to an `int` before calling `Math.Abs`

Answer (score 5):

What value would you have it be? there is no `32768` in `short` - only `32767`.

You could write your own method, of course:

```
public static short LossyAbs(short value)
{
    if(value >= 0) return value;
    if(value == short.MinValue) return short.MaxValue;
    return -value;
}
```

but this is lossy in that it sort-of loses a value. Perhaps a better idea is: don't use `short.MinValue` if you intend to (potentially) negate it. Limiting yourself to `-32767` would make this go away.

Answer (score 1):

Convert short[] array to int[] array.