# OverflowException on DateTime difference calculation

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, floating-point

I get a strange error on this little snippet:

```
private int CalculateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    var difference = date1 - date2;
    return Math.Abs((int)difference.TotalSeconds);
}
```

In my case I'm calculating a difference of 3520789176.4909997 total seconds. The program throws an exception I´ve never seen in ten years of C# coding:

`System.OverflowException: "Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid."`

**I´m pretty sure it´s related to floating point arithmetics**, but I don´t understand the details and I just need a sufficient solution to determine the difference of the two date values.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265381/c-sharp-short-error-negating-the-minimum-value-of-a-twos-complement-number-is-i

Comment: You’re pretty sure of something that’s false.

Comment: Int32.MaxValue seconds is less than 70 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the when the a double exceeds the range of values that can be expressed in an `int`—which is [-2,147,483,648](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue.aspx) to [2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx), the result is undefined according to the C# specification (See [*Jeppe Stig Nielsen*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880571/overflowexception-on-datetime-difference-calculation/17880651?noredirect=1#comment26289202_17880651) below), but in the .NET implementation, is `int.MinValue`. So when you convert `difference` to an `int`, it takes the value, -2,147,483,648 which then cannot be negated using `Math.Abs`

If you convert this method to use `long` instead, it should work:

```
private long CalculateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    var difference = date1 - date2;
    return Math.Abs((long)difference.TotalSeconds);
}
```

You could also solve this by simply converting to `int` after you've taken the absolute value:

```
private int CalculateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    var difference = date1 - date2;
    return (int)Math.Abs(difference.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: You: _it takes the closest value, -2,147,483,648_ No, it takes, in this specific case, the ***farthest*** value. It is possible (not entirely certain) that `Int32.MinValue` is produced in all "impossible" cases. The C# Spec says: (next comment)

Comment: "In an `unchecked` context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.
Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type."

Comment: Another solution would be `difference.Duration().Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond` (and should still return `long`). Looks more clumsy, but avoids converting an integer to a floating point number and back to an integer again.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right! I assumed OP had simply mixed up the order of operands and the *actual* value was `-3520789176.4909997`, but it seems if the value is >= `2147483648` or <= `-2147483648` the result will always `int.MinValue`. `Double.NaN`, `Double.PositiveInfinity`, and `Double.NegativeInfinity` produce the same. I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx): value of Int.Maxvalue is 2,147,483,647

Your number seems to be greater than that.