# SQL Server Reporting Services - Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid (reproduced)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I have a legacy report (.rdl), which breaks when a certain data is passed. Generally, a stored procedure return data in the following format:

- RowID
- ColumnOrderID
- ColumnValue

Then, there is some logic and the following line breaks:

```
Lookup(  ColumnOrderID  + 100000,    ColumnOrderID   + RowID * 100000,   ColumnValue,   "smBaseData")
```

when the `RowId` is `105942` and `ColumnOrderID` is `1022`. The strange is, it is working fine with smaller and bigger values for the `RowId` column.

The exact error is:

[image]

and here is some more debug info:

> processing!ReportServer_0-1!29a8!03/16/2023-14:48:16:: w WARN: Data
> source 'smds': Report processing has been aborted.
> processing!ReportServer_0-1!29a8!03/16/2023-14:48:16:: e ERROR:
> Throwing
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
> [AbnormalTermination:ReportProcessing],
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
> An error has occurred during report processing. --->
> System.OverflowException: Negating the minimum value of a twos
> complement number is invalid.    at System.Math.AbsHelper(Int32 value)
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Scalability.ScalableDictionary`2.HashToSlot(ScalableDictionaryNode node, Int32 hashCode, Int32 level)    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Scalability.ScalableDictionary`2.Find(ScalableDictionaryNodeReference
> nodeRef, Int32 hashCode, TKey key, Int32 level, TValue& value,
> IDisposable& containingNodeRef)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Scalability.ScalableDictionary`2.Find(ScalableDictionaryNodeReference nodeRef, Int32 hashCode, TKey key, Int32 level, TValue& value, IDisposable& containingNodeRef)    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Scalability.ScalableDictionary`2.TryGetAndPin(TKey
> key, TValue& value, IDisposable& reference)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.TablixProcessing.RuntimeLookupProcessing.NextRow()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.TablixProcessing.RuntimeOnDemandDataSetObj.NextRow()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.TablixProcessing.RuntimeOnDemandDataSet.ProcessRow(RecordRow
> row, Int32 rowNumber)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.ProcessRows()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.InitializeRowSourceAndProcessRows(ExecutedQuery
> existingQuery)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.Process(ExecutedQuery
> existingQuery)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.ProcessConcurrent(Object
> threadSet)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;

I have no experience with SQL Server Reporting Services, so any help or idea is welcome.

---

I have created [sample example](https://codeshare.io/X8xmBM) reproducing the error. In order to test you need to save this code as .rdl file.

Comment: It will be good to know what value is being looked up and what use is * 100000 in the expression. See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265381/c-sharp-short-error-negating-the-minimum-value-of-a-twos-complement-number-is-i) helps to understand the reason for error.

Comment: ColumnOrderID   + RowID * 100000 looks to be generating 10.5 billion.   Perhaps numeric overflow of an INT ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I am thinking about overflow, too, but this can not explain why the report is working fine with larger numbers. For example, it is constantly generating with row Ids greater then one million.

Comment: I don't understand how larger numbers are working but looking at the debug into you provided shows that Math.AbsHelper is being called which looks like it takes an Int32. Int 32 has maximum value of 2,147,483,647. I'm assuming the `lookup` is part of a larger expression? It might be the error is actually elsewhere, hard to tell though. Maybe create a new report, hardcode some values in a dataset and then add simple table with your input values and the result of the lookup to see if it is indeed the lookup that is the issue, as you don't use `ABS()` in the lookup, I suspect its elsewhere.

Comment: @AlanSchofield That's what I have done. I have removed all the other expressions (one by one) till this one is left. Then, I remove all the records returned by the stored procedure (one by one) till finding the one causing the issue.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I can't be of more help, it's off the ABS seems be getting called though for a lookup. Beyond my knowledge though....

Comment: just throwing ideas out there.. what if you cast it as a bigint ?

Comment: @Harry Thanks, I have try passing the both values as BIGINT (originally, `rowid` as BIGINT, and `ColumnOrderID` as INT), but nothing changed.

Comment: I have create a sample rdl file in order to reproduce the issue. There is link in the question body.

Comment: Can't download RDL!

Comment: @Harry it is working now. Their services was gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the rdl that was supplied and updated the columnvalue to have something meaningful so I could see if it did return something. I then worked out what the report expression would return - so the first row would equate to 10593100101. So I used that value as a lookup value in the expression. I then changed your expression to the following and it worked for me :

```
=Lookup(  Cdbl(10593100101),  Cdbl(Fields!ColumnOrderID.Value + Fields!RowID.Value * 100000), Fields!ColumnValue.Value, "smBaseData")
```

It just needed a type conversion.